# how can I return non const objects with set operator->

Tags: c++

I get the error:

> no matching function for call to ‘mem::GPAchunk::get_memory(size_t&) const

and a note:

> passing ‘const mem::GPAchunk*’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers

I think the problem is this functions of the set library

```
operator->() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return static_cast<_Link_type>(_M_node)->_M_valptr(); }
```

this is the function I call

```
void mem::GPAchunk::get_memory(const size_t &amount){
    m_chunkSize -= amount;
    m_bPtrData = m_bPtrData + amount;
}
```

I call it with

```
i->get_memory(neededSize);
```

`i` is defined here

```
for (auto i = m_freeChunks.begin(); i != m_freeChunks.end(); i++)
```

Comment: Where's your [MCVE]?

Comment: Hi Treepower. Welcome to stack overflow. You'll always find someone wanting to help, but you'll need to provide more context in your questions to get it. Understanding what you want to accomplish is the first step. Your operator returns a const, so you should not try to change this, specially if this is an external library. On the other side, we don't know what you want to accomplish, and the code you share doesn't tell the whole story. What is m_freeChunks? What do you want to do with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you have `std::set<GPAchunk>`.

`std::set` elements are immutable / `const`. You can still cast away constness and modify the elements as long as you do not modify element's members which are used as the set's key.

Comment: so does that mean if I want to change variables which are used in the less operator than I need a other library  PS: thanks for the quick answer

Comment: @treepower If you'd like to change variables which are used in the less operator than you need to remove the element from the set, update the key and insert it again.